# how to control the supplement when perform bit shift

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

i want to perform below two kind of bit shift in Java, but not sure how can i do it, can anyone give some some hint?

```
**Case one:**
e.g original number in binary is "101"
left shift and put a "1" on the right most
    left shift:        "011"
    left shift again : "111"
```

seems like this case can be done by   "(number<<1) | 1"

```
**Case two:**
e.g original number in binary is "101"
left shift and put a "0" on the right most
    left shift:         "010"
    left shift again:   "100"
```

but not sure how to do second case. i tried with "(number<<1) & 0", but it turn the whole thing to 0.

Comment: Hint: What operation can you do that will *always* result in a `0` in the least significant bit? The answer is quite similar to your first answer.

Comment: i tried to do "(number<<1) & 0", but it turn the whole thing to be zero.   how can i only operate on the least significant bit?

Comment: Ummmm... have you considered using left shift (only)???

Comment: My apologies, meant "operation" instead of "binary operation". @fabian basically got it...

Answer (score 0):

Use a mask, something like:

```
int MASK = 0x7; // three 1s at the LSD

int myVar = 0x5; // 101 in binary
int myResult;

...

myResult = ((myVar << 1) | 1) & MASK; // to add 1 in the LSD

...

myResult = ((myVar << 1)) & MASK; // to add 0 in the LSD
```